# sys.database_files and sys.master_files show different physical_name values

Tags: sql-server

I received the following alert:

> The operating system returned error 21(The device is not ready.) to SQL Server during a read at offset 0x0000000012c000 in file 'C:\VeeamFLR\UK->SB->SQL11_4406bb77\Volume3\DATA\MyDB10_STAGE.mdf'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and...

The following script shows `sys.database_files` and `sys.master_files` have different `physical_name` values:

```
declare @dbname varchar(30)

set @dbname = (select name from sys.master_files where physical_name like 'C:\VeeamFLR\%.mdf')

select name as 'MasterFiles', physical_name as 'FullPath' from sys.master_files where physical_name like 'C:\VeeamFLR\%.%df'order by physical_name desc
exec('USE '+ @dbName + '; select name as ''DatabaseFiles'', physical_name as ''FullPath'' from sys.database_files')
```

Results:

`MasterFiles              FullPath`

`------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`MyDB10_STAGE        C:\VeeamFLR\UK-SB-SQL11_4406bb77\Volume3\DATA\MyDB10_STAGE.mdf`

`MyDB10_STAGE_log    C:\VeeamFLR\UK-SB-SQL11_4406bb77\Volume2\Logs\MyDB10_STAGE_log.ldf`

`(2 row(s) affected`

`DatabaseFiles            FullPath`

`------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`MyDB10_STAGE        E:\DATA\MyDB10_STAGE.mdf`

`MyDB10_STAGE_log    D:\Logs\MyDB10_STAGE_log.ldf`

`(2 row(s) affected)`

The `sys.database`_files value is correct. (`Sys.master_files` refers to a previous Veeam restore mount point. Not sure why). I've tried a `detach` and re-`attach` with the correct path specified:

```
-- detach:
ALTER DATABASE MyDB10_STAGE SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'MyDB10_STAGE'
GO

-- No need to move physical files as actually already in correct location

USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE MyDB10_STAGE ON
( FILENAME = N'E:\DATA\MyDB10_STAGE.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'D:\LOGS\MyDB10_STAGE_log.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH
GO

--Put database in multi user mode again:

ALTER DATABASE MyDB10_STAGE SET MULTI_USER
GO
```

But this has not updated `physical_name` in `sys.master_files`. Can anyone recommend how to update physical_name in sys.master_files to the correct value please?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the SQL Server service?

Comment: No, I hadn't.  Restarted it and the problem disappeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation for [`sys.database_files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql) or [`sys.master_files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql), or even [`sys.sysfiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysfiles-transact-sql) or [`sys.sysaltfiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysaltfiles-transact-sql), but there will likely be several state changes that won't be truly reflected across all file-related catalog views until the SQL Server service has been restarted. If the changes are isolated to a single database, it might be worth trying to set the database `OFFLINE` and `ONLINE` again, but I haven't confirmed that will work.